# how to use xpath get all child node text?

Tags: python, html, xpath

```
<tr>
<td width="120" align="right" class="tit">Name：</td>
<td style="width:345px;word-break:break-all;">
<a style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0066ff;cursor: pointer" href="javascript:_search('pin','Jack');">Jack</a>;
<a style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0066ff;cursor: pointer" href="javascript:_search('pin','Eva');">Eva</a>;
</td>
</tr>
```

I want return "Jack;Eva", but I just get Jack with below code. How to get all names? There are different counts of names.

```
html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Name")]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()')[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this (removed `[1]`), and you have to remove trailing `[0]` which limit your results at the first match:

```sh
//td[contains(text(),"Name")]/following-sibling::td/a/text()
```

### Output

```
Jack
Eva
```